# Can we save data from the textarea into a text file?

Tags: java, flex4

I am developing a web application using Adobe Flex. I would like to retrieve the data entered in the text area and save them into a new text file.

Can anyone please let me know the details to write data into a text file ?

Thanks,
Serenity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you trying to store the data? on the server or client side? You will have have access to client's file system to write a file (due to security reasons). If you need to create the file on server, you will have to submit the data onto a servlet, jsp or some controller action (for frameworks like spring,struts etc). And then write it onto your server's file system.

**Update:** Since, you are a beginner, I suggest you read: [Create Flex 4 and Java Web applications](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/wa-flex4javaapps/index.html?ca=drs-) . The tutorial is actually saving data into database. You can instead, save the contents into a file. And you might want to change the field types in the flex form. But this tutorial can give you a start :)

Comment: Actually, I would like to store the file in the server itself. Can you please provide me an example if possible ?

Comment: where are you having the trouble? and with what part? I hope you have the flex form created, and able to submit data to an url.. all you need to do is get the submitted data and use java to save it into a file.

Comment: Alright, I understand the procedure to send the data from the text area to servlet. However, can u please confirm how to save the data before sending it to servlet ?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand that! why do you want to save before sending to servlet? you cannot save a file on the client.. flex is running on your browser and your browser cannot save a file (in this case)

Comment: I am able to save the text area into a new text file but  I need to save the file directly into the server. I understand that I need to upload the file into server as soon as it is saved in the temporary location.